# Handling favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am receiving a lot of errors on the server for an asp.net MVC 5 site for:

```
example.com/favicon.ico
example.com/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png
example.com/robots.txt
```

etc

NewRelic doesn't tell me the source but these errors occur frequently.

I understand that you can specify the favicon & apple-touch icons in the HTML of the page using a link as specified here:
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons

However - that is a lot of HTML to be adding to every page - and my main objective is to stop the errors - and something is looking for these files in the root.

How can I just simply map a folder to the root of the domain to put all these files in?

Also is there any disadvantage to just doing things this way and not using the extensive HTML required to point to a folder with these items in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply place the files in the root - doh.